# Broken Pipe Exception - org.apache.catalina.connector.clientabortexception java.io.ioexception broken pipe

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, catalina

***I have deployed my project in the cloud but when i try to log-in, the following exception is coming, i am unable to figure out the cause for this exception.Can anyone please help me on that.***

Exception catched by Spring MVC:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1853) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeRaw(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:610) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter$Lf2SpacesIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:479) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeObjectEntrySeparator(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:302) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writePPFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:394) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:231) ~[jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:503) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1887) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:198) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [tomcat8-servlet-3.1-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [tomcat8-servlet-3.1-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:673) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:127) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:173) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:116) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:503) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.15]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```